# Разработка на Node.js с использованием базы данных SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sql-server, sqlite

Я создаю вебсайт для анонимного голосования на Node.js. В конце голосования мне нужно подсчитать количество ответов, чтоб было анонимно и отображало только ответы и количество, сколько проголосовало за этот ответ.

```
app.get('/results', function (req, res) {

 
    if(typeof req.query.id != 'undefined'){


    var db = new sqlite3.Database('./data.db');
    var id = req.query.id;
    console.log("ID: " + id);

    query_str = "SELECT DISTINCT answer FROM test WHERE pollID = " + id + ";";
    
    db.all(query_str, (err, results) => {
    
        if(err) { console.log(err.message); } 
        else {

            var content = createTemplate();
            for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {    
                console.log(results[i].answer);

                query_str2 = "SELECT MAX(answer) AS answer,COUNT('" + results[i] + "') AS Count FROM test GROUP BY (answer);";
                
                db.all(query_str2, (err, results2) => {
                    
                    if(err) { console.log(err.message); } 
                    else {
                        var content = createTemplate();
                        content += results2; 
                        res.status(200).send(content + "</body></html>");
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    });
    db.close();}
    else {
        res.status(200).send("error");
    }

    
    
})
```

И вот с такого датасета он считывает данные:

[image: dataset for the code]

Как мне записать правильно запрос? Он у меня обозначен как  **query_str2**

Comment: `SELECT answer, COUNT(*) as Count FROM test GROUP BY answer`

Comment: @Yaant спасибо большое, работает!